# Sonar C++ Community plug-in

Tags: c, sonarqube

I want to get a clarification that this plug-in only works for C++ and won't work for C. I tried to run with C code in the src directory and it doesnt return anything unlike the C++ projects.

Anyway for me to run C code for free (Community versions), my cppcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c++ community plugin will by default import any c files found under project dir, the parsing will be done using a compatibility mode (so it might not be complete). Default properties and values for this to work are:

sonar.cxx.cFilesPatterns - *.c,*.C

sonar.cxx.suffixes.sources - .cxx,.cpp,.cc,.c

sonar.cxx.suffixes.headers - .hxx,.hpp,.hh,.h

See details in documentation [wiki](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Supported-configuration-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that you'll get an answer to this question on StackOverflow. I would ask this question by directly creating an issue on the relating github project : https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx

Comment: I agree totally, but this should probably be a comment since it doesn't answer the question

Comment: agree, sorry for that !